# Upload and build with Phonegap Build API

Tags: cordova, wget, phonegap-build

I'm trying to do an automatic upload of content to Phonegap Build servers. However, I'm facing some issues.

The build API pages has two sets of authentication (which is fine). One is token and the other is http-auth.

It doesn't really work that great for me:

```
wget --user=XXX --password=XXX https://build.phonegap.com/token

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-08-10 12:21:44 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Using another approach

```
wget --user=XXX --password=XXX https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/me

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Reusing existing connection to build.phonegap.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 629 [application/json]
```

Second example gives me a chunk of json with inlined indicators for apps, keys, etc. This is fine, but there's not auth key in it which I need to be able to post upload build content.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/token` endpoint requires a `POST` request ([doc](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/developer_api_authentication.md.html)):

```
wget --user=XXX --password=XXX --post-data="" https://build.phonegap.com/token
```